# Is it valid to make this integral and summation switch?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

Is this ok to

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \int_a^b x^2 dx$$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \int_a^b x^2 dx$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^b\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i  x^2 dx$$

since rewriting the infinite summation as a limit of partial sums then makes the summation finite and since the integration over the interval [a,b] is is also finite, then the swap is ok to make.

Just wanted to confirm.

Thanks,

Comment: See Fubini-Tonnelli theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem. You can treat a sum as an integral

Comment: Yes, you can interchange the finite sum with the integral.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation @Dr.MV.

Comment: Can I take this just one step further @Dr.MV, if the integral were instead improper, so that either one or both of the limits of integration were -/+ infinity, but this integral is known to converge, and also the infinite sum, with summand $a_i$ times the convergent integral, is known to be summable, then can I swap the improper integral with the infinite sum?  Thanks,

Comment: Basically, sort of avoiding the stringent rule of Fubini, and not checking for the absolute value of the summand / integrand to converge to a finite sum / integral, but still justifying the swap, @Dr.MV

Comment: Also, I am happy to accept your answer, if you instead post an answer instead of comments - thanks, @Dr.MV.

Comment: Yes, it applies for convergent improper integrals since the sum of integrals is the integral of the sum.

Comment: Ah, of course @Dr.MV -- thanks so much for the nice, fundamental answer.

Comment: Sorry @Dr.MV, one last question, if you don't mind:  what you last stated is the linearity property of the integral operator - but does the concept of linearity fall apart for an infinite sum of integrals, so that the infinite sum of the integrals is no longer the integral of the infinite sum?  Thanks,

Comment: So that, what I did in my question post, first breaking it down as a *limit* of partial (finite) sums, then making the swap, because of linearity / finiteness, is the right way to go, and that linearity may not be applicable otherwise, @Dr.MV?  Thanks,

Comment: Provided the limit remains outside the integral, the interchange is legit.  In order to bring the limit inside the integral, one would need to justify the interchange.  Dominated convergence or uniform convergence are the usual tools.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much for your time, @Dr.MV.

Comment: You're welcome;  my pleasure.